# SWT: input validation: prevent input of sub and superscript numbers

Tags: java, validation, input, swt

i am validating the input from an swt text widget and i fail to prevent input of sub and superscript numbers. My goal is to allow only numeric input. I am using a SWT verify listener, my code is something like this:

```
[...]
Text input = new Text (parent, SWT.CENTER);
input.addListener(SWT.VERIFY, new Listener(){
public void handleEvent(Event e){
    if ( (e.character >= '0' && e.character <= '9') || e.character == SWT.BS || e.character == SWT.DEL){
        e.doit = true;
    } else {
        e.doit = false;
    }
}
});
[...]
```

i have tried to filter it manually with something like this, but that didn't do the job:

```
private boolean isSup(character c){
    if (c == '^0'){
        return true;
    } else if(c == '^1'){
        return true;
    } [...] else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is probably a simple straightforward way to do it, but i don't see it and google didn't provide the answer either.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this Unicode super and subscript numbers you are asking about (such as U+2080 for subscript 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution that works for me; i post it here in the hope it will help someone else.

```
input = new Text(parent, style);    
input.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener(){
        e.doit = false;
        String DIGIT = "[0-9]*";
        if (e.text.matches(DIGIT)){
            e.doit = true;
        }
    });
```

This solution does allow leading zeros, but those are not an issue for my purpose. I do not know, why comparing characters  arithmetically does not work, but e.text and its matches method work just fine.